# vaadin: sometimes / often I get java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null before session get destroyed when Push is used

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

On Vaadin flow 14 sometimes it happens to get a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null` when Push is used before the session get destroyed.

Is this normal? Can I ignore the this exception?

I post the full stacktrace:

```
2021-07-31 16:12:49,957 [Scheduler-1277181601-1] INFO  c.v.f.s.c.AtmospherePushConnection - Timeout waiting for messages to be sent to client before disconnect
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.BroadcasterFuture.get(BroadcasterFuture.java:126)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.AtmospherePushConnection.disconnect(AtmospherePushConnection.java:329)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.setPushConnection(UIInternals.java:449)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.setSession(UIInternals.java:401)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.removeUI(VaadinSession.java:575)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.lambda$null$65d65655$1(VaadinService.java:663)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:431)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:392)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.lambda$fireSessionDestroy$9c853e43$1(VaadinService.java:653)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:2039)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:663)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.ensureAccessQueuePurged(VaadinService.java:2005)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.accessSession(VaadinService.java:1972)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.access(VaadinSession.java:951)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.fireSessionDestroy(VaadinService.java:644)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.valueUnbound(VaadinSession.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session.unbindValue(Session.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session.callSessionAttributeListeners(Session.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session.finishInvalidate(Session.java:1072)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.invalidate(SessionHandler.java:1220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager.expireAll(DefaultSessionIdManager.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.scavenge(SessionHandler.java:1264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper.scavenge(HouseKeeper.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper$Runner.run(HouseKeeper.java:61)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Just after this session get destroyed:

```
2021-07-31 16:12:49,962 [Scheduler-1277181601-1] DEBUG t.a.SessionLogger - session destroyed, id: node01k3qkglhhptjbvu1izf5wd1da60
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception is harmless if I understand the situation correctly. I assume the user has dropped from the network or is otherwise unreachable in a way that didn't previously trigger an explicitly detected termination of the push connection. Vaadin sends one last message to the client side when the session is expired, but sending this message leads to a connection timeout.

This situation could potentially be handled in a better way from Vaadin so to avoid throwing an exception that might cause other cleanup to not be run.